# Gradle trouble after updating Android Studio

Tags: android, gradle, build, android-support-library

I have updated Android Studio to 1.4. 
Since that I have big trouble with my Gradle. 
I have now Gradle version 2.2.1.

So at first I opened Android SDK Manager and updated everything that was possible. 
After that I typed the current SDKVersion into the build.gradle file.

But still my project contains errors with gradle. 
I do not know, what else I could do. 
The whole project has worked before.

```
My build.gradle file: 

apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 22
    buildToolsVersion '23.0.1'
    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.jublikon.timerapp"
        minSdkVersion 20
        targetSdkVersion 22
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
    sourceSets {
        main { res.srcDirs = ['src/main/res', 'src/main/res/drawable/ic_action_search.png'] }
    }
    productFlavors {
    }
}

dependencies {
    compile fileTree(include: ['*.jar'], dir: 'libs')
    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:22.0.0'
    compile 'com.android.support:recyclerview-v7:22.0.0'
    compile 'com.android.support:cardview-v7:22.0.0'
    compile 'com.mcxiaoke.volley:library:1.0.6'
    compile 'com.nispok:snackbar:2.10.+'
    compile 'com.joanzapata.pdfview:android-pdfview:1.0.+@aar'
    compile 'jp.wasabeef:recyclerview-animators:1.2.0@aar'
}
```

And the Error Log:

```
Information:Gradle tasks [:app:generateDebugSources, :app:generateDebugAndroidTestSources, :app:compileDebugSources, :app:compileDebugAndroidTestSources]
:app:preBuild UP-TO-DATE
:app:preDebugBuild UP-TO-DATE
:app:checkDebugManifest
:app:preReleaseBuild UP-TO-DATE
:app:prepareComAndroidSupportAppcompatV72200Library UP-TO-DATE
:app:prepareComAndroidSupportCardviewV72200Library UP-TO-DATE
:app:prepareComAndroidSupportRecyclerviewV72200Library UP-TO-DATE
:app:prepareComAndroidSupportSupportV42200Library UP-TO-DATE
:app:prepareComJoanzapataPdfviewAndroidPdfview104Library UP-TO-DATE
:app:prepareComNispokSnackbar21010Library UP-TO-DATE
:app:prepareJpWasabeefRecyclerviewAnimators120Library UP-TO-DATE
:app:prepareDebugDependencies
:app:compileDebugAidl
:app:compileDebugRenderscript
:app:generateDebugBuildConfig UP-TO-DATE
:app:generateDebugAssets UP-TO-DATE
:app:mergeDebugAssets UP-TO-DATE
:app:generateDebugResValues UP-TO-DATE
:app:generateDebugResources
:app:mergeDebugResources
AAPT: /Users/Martin/some/path/app/build/intermediates/exploded-aar/com.android.support/appcompat-v7/22.0.0/res/drawable-hdpi-v4/abc_spinner_mtrl_am_alpha.9.png: libpng warning: iCCP: Not recognizing known sRGB profile that has been edited
AAPT: /Users/Martin/some/path/app/src/main/res/drawable-mdpi/ic_ads.png: libpng warning: iCCP: Not recognizing known sRGB profile that has been edited
AAPT: /Users/Martin/some/path/app/src/main/res/drawable-xhdpi/ic_ads.png: libpng warning: iCCP: Not recognizing known sRGB profile that has been edited
AAPT: /Users/Martin/some/path/app/src/main/res/drawable-xxxhdpi/ic_ads.png: libpng warning: iCCP: Not recognizing known sRGB profile that has been edited
AAPT: /Users/Martin/some/path/app/src/main/res/drawable-xxhdpi/ic_ads.png: libpng warning: iCCP: Not recognizing known sRGB profile that has been edited
AAPT: /Users/Martin/some/path/app/src/main/res/drawable-hdpi/ic_ads.png: libpng warning: iCCP: Not recognizing known sRGB profile that has been edited
:app:processDebugManifest UP-TO-DATE
:app:processDebugResources
:app:generateDebugSources
:app:preDebugAndroidTestBuild UP-TO-DATE
:app:prepareDebugAndroidTestDependencies
:app:compileDebugAndroidTestAidl
:app:processDebugAndroidTestManifest UP-TO-DATE
:app:compileDebugAndroidTestRenderscript
:app:generateDebugAndroidTestBuildConfig UP-TO-DATE
:app:generateDebugAndroidTestAssets UP-TO-DATE
:app:mergeDebugAndroidTestAssets UP-TO-DATE
:app:generateDebugAndroidTestResValues UP-TO-DATE
:app:generateDebugAndroidTestResources
:app:mergeDebugAndroidTestResources
:app:processDebugAndroidTestResources
:app:generateDebugAndroidTestSources
:app:compileDebugJavaWithJavac
/Users/Martin/some/path/app/src/main/java/com/some/path/activity/MainActivity.java
Error:(37, 61) error: incompatible types: Fragment cannot be converted to FragmentDrawer
Error:(38, 112) error: incompatible types: android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar cannot be converted to android.widget.Toolbar
Error:(70, 28) error: incompatible types: FragmentEinstellungen cannot be converted to Fragment
/Users/Martin/some/path/app/src/main/java/com/some/path/fragment/Drawer/FragmentDrawer.java
Error:(24, 13) error: cannot find symbol class RecyclerView
Error:(152, 63) error: package RecyclerView does not exist
Error:(157, 61) error: cannot find symbol class RecyclerView
Error:(176, 46) error: cannot find symbol class RecyclerView
Error:(186, 34) error: cannot find symbol class RecyclerView
Error:(69, 26) error: cannot find symbol class RecyclerView
Error:(93, 25) error: no suitable constructor found for ActionBarDrawerToggle(Activity,DrawerLayout,android.widget.Toolbar,int,int)
constructor ActionBarDrawerToggle.ActionBarDrawerToggle(Activity,DrawerLayout,android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar,int,int) is not applicable
(argument mismatch; android.widget.Toolbar cannot be converted to android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar)
constructor ActionBarDrawerToggle.<T>ActionBarDrawerToggle(Activity,android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar,DrawerLayout,T,int,int) is not applicable
(cannot infer type-variable(s) T
(actual and formal argument lists differ in length))
where T is a type-variable:
T extends Drawable,DrawerToggle declared in constructor <T>ActionBarDrawerToggle(Activity,android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar,DrawerLayout,T,int,int)
Error:(175, 9) error: method does not override or implement a method from a supertype
Error:(185, 9) error: method does not override or implement a method from a supertype
/Users/some/path/fragment/Einstellungen/FragmentEinstellungen.java
Error:(23, 13) error: cannot find symbol class RecyclerView
Error:(41, 26) error: cannot find symbol class RecyclerView
Error:(51, 37) error: cannot find symbol class RecyclerView
Error:(91, 21) error: no suitable method found for add(int,FragmentQrCode)
method FragmentTransaction.add(Fragment,String) is not applicable
(argument mismatch; int cannot be converted to Fragment)
method FragmentTransaction.add(int,Fragment) is not applicable
(argument mismatch; FragmentQrCode cannot be converted to Fragment)
Note: Some input files use or override a deprecated API.
Note: Recompile with -Xlint:deprecation for details.
Note: /some/path/HelperClasses/RecyclerView/SimpleSectionedRecyclerViewAdapter.java uses unchecked or unsafe operations.
Note: Recompile with -Xlint:unchecked for details.
Note: Some messages have been simplified; recompile with -Xdiags:verbose to get full output
Error:Execution failed for task ':app:compileDebugJavaWithJavac'.
> Compilation failed; see the compiler error output for details.
Information:BUILD FAILED
Information:Total time: 11.587 secs
Information:17 errors
Information:0 warnings
Information:See complete output in console
```

Comment: have you upgraded your support lib?

Comment: In the SDK manager there was a support lib. And I have updated it

Comment: It seems that the issues are in the MainActivity.java. Can you post this class?

Comment: In all Fragment classes there are issues either. All of the classes with issues have in common that they are support libraries...

Comment: Make sure you have compile "com.android.support:appcompat-v7:23.0.1" in your build gradle. clean build your application.